# How to use Parse in a watchOS 2 Application Xcode 7 beta 5

Tags: parse-platform, watchkit, storekit, watchos-2, xcode7-beta5

I want to use Parse.com in my watchkit app but it cant be built because storekit files cant be found. I have added the framework but it doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: I think it's not possible yet as Parse requires some frameworks that are not available in WatchOS 2 yet. I hope I'm wrong or there will be a solution soon, because I'm looking for the same thing!

Answer (score 0):

watchOS only allows a subset of the iOS Frameworks to be accessed, so at this stage you will not be able to use `Parse.framework` in your watchOS 2 app.